# How to authenticate with reddit using RCurl

Tags: r, curl, oauth, reddit, rcurl

I've been trying to authenticate with Reddit from R using RCurl based on this example from [Reddit's github](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example):

```
 curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=password&username=reddit_bot&password=snoo' --user   'p-jcoLKBynTLew:gko_LXELoV07ZBNUXrvWZfzE3aI' https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
```

I've tried to convert it to an RCurl command like so:

```
postForm("https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token?grant_type=password",
     username = "MyUserName",
     password = "MyPassword",
     .opts = list(userpwd = "MyClientid:MySecret")
     )
```

But I get an error: `Error: Unauthorized`

I'm not sure what I'm doing really with the conversion of the curl command to Rcurl. Thanks for any help you could provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this httr code:

```
library(httr)

POST("https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
  body = list(
    grant_type = "password",
    username = "MyUserName",
    password = "MyPassword"
  ),
  encode = "form",
  authenticate("p-jcoLKBynTLew", "gko_LXELoV07ZBNUXrvWZfzE3aI")
)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! For anyone else coming across this the "T" in grant_Type needs to be lowercase in order to work.